# Защита htaccess от перебора пассов

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Заблочил папку через Authtype. Какой я молодец.
Вот только как сообразить защиту от перебора?
Проблема в том что не хочу включать пхп на этом домене. Ибо используется как файлопойка от файлового хостинга.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, существуют сторонние решения, банящие по ипу, существует вариант лимита на количество запросов в единицу времени. Однако в случае большого "интереса" могут брутить с нескольких машин. Поэтому я предлагаю вариант, являющийся с одной стороны достаточно надежным, а другой стороны не требующий обширных инсталляций стороннего софта и прочих ухищрений. Суть в том, чтобы разрешать доступ только с доверенных ипов и подсетей, типа такого:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from [ip]/[mask]
```

Кроме того:

- исключите возможность
     несанкционированного доступа к
     .htaccess и .htpasswd
- для генерации паролей используйте максимально криптостойкую хэш-функцию (насколько позволяет ОС и сама утилита), это затруднит брут и подбор с помощью радужных таблиц
- релоад страницы и перенаправление можно осуществлять с помощью тега meta - перенаправления через 10 с на страницу с тяжелым фоном, скажем, которая грузится долго. После очередной отправки запроса будет опять грузится эта заполненная пробелами, допустим, страница... в общем можно что-то придумать и без php.
- ну и прислушайтесь к рекомендациям Apache.org

> Web password files such as those
> managed by htpasswd should not be
> within the Web server's URI space --
> that is, they should not be fetchable
> with a browser.
>
> This program is not safe as a setuid
> executable. Do not make it setuid.
>
> The use of the -b option is
> discouraged, since when it is used the
> unencrypted password appears on the
> command line.
>
> When using the crypt() algorithm, note
> that only the first 8 characters of
> the password are used to form the
> password. If the supplied password is
> longer, the extra characters will be
> silently discarded.
>
> The SHA encryption format does not use
> salting: for a given password, there
> is only one encrypted representation.
> The crypt() and MD5 formats permute
> the representation by prepending a
> random salt string, to make dictionary
> attacks against the passwords more
> difficult.

Comment: Да тут дело не в том что могут сломать 20значный пасс в md5, а в том что боюсь могу повесить и так нагруженный сервак.

Comment: То есть вам нужна защита от перегрузки сервера? Введите [ограничения](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/) на количество соединений с одного адреса.